# Sharepoint Webpart posting data to Application Page via PostBackUrl

Tags: c#, sharepoint, web-parts, applicationpage

I have a Webpart that contains a couple of dropdowns on an update panel. There is a submit button that has the PostBackUrl set to a sharepoint Application Page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ClassSelector" runat="server" Enabled="False" 
    AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="ClassSelector_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="-null-">Select Class...</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Class 1</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Show Page" Enabled="False" 
                PostBackUrl="~/_layouts/MyWebParts/MyAppPage.aspx" />
```

This works in redirecting the browser to the Application Page I have created, but I am having trouble accessing the form data.

On the Page_Load function of the Application Page I have the following debugging code.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = "";

    foreach (String s in Page.Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        Label1.Text += s + ": " + Page.Request.Form[s] + "<br />";
    }

}
```

This shows that the data I need has in fact been posted to the page.

```
ctl00$m$g_24a73cf8_8190_4ddb_b38b_bf523b12dbd3$ctl00$SemesterSelector: 28
ctl00$m$g_24a73cf8_8190_4ddb_b38b_bf523b12dbd3$ctl00$ClassSelector: 11-0021-A
```

But when I try to access this as:

```
Page.Request.Form["ClassSelector"]
```

Nothing is returned. I know I must be missing something simple here, but I am not sure what.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the ASP.NET master page prefix problem!  One of my favorites.

The master page for your application page puts a prefix in front of your server-side controls so that they will be unique.  If you end up access your control via the `Form` collection, you have to access it using not only the control ID, but also the ContentPlaceholder prefix.  That's why you see such a large ID dumped out of your debugging logic.

If you want to programmatically get to the ID of the control, you can use `FindControl`, but you'll have to target the apppropriate content placeholder scope for this.  Here's a good tutorial/explanation [here](http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials/control-id-naming-in-content-pages-cs) (which really emphasizes how complex this can get!).

Of course, the other option you can use is just hard-coding the control id based on what you're seeing from your debugging code...but that won't be reliable if you change content placeholders or more your control to a different container.

I guess the answer depends on how static your controls will be.

Hope this helps.  Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Well to access it that way you would have to use

```
Page.Request.Form["ctl00$m$g_24a73cf8_8190_4ddb_b38b_bf523b12dbd3$ctl00$ClassSelector"]
```

As you can actually see from your code where you set the label text to s plus `Request.Form[s]`

Comment: This wont work as the id will change. I deployed my solution to another sharepoint server and got the following response.

ctl00$m$g_c690a07a_e525_4c4d_9c98_efb436828ec7$ctl00$SemesterSelector: 28
ctl00$m$g_c690a07a_e525_4c4d_9c98_efb436828ec7$ctl00$ClassSelector: 11-0021-A